# Announcing a site sponsorship for Salesforce Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

We're excited to announce that **[Gearset](https://gearset.com/) will be sponsoring the Salesforce Stack Exchange site** for the upcoming year, as a part of [our site sponsorship program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange) and after successful experiences on both our [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) and [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) sites, as well as [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), more recently.

If this is the first time you've heard about site sponsorships, you're likely to have questions — to reiterate some of the clarifications we've made on the previous posts surrounding this site sponsorship program:

#### How will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown in top right of the header of the site in a manner that's similar to how you can see [Octopus Deploy's sponsorship on Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9680/264207). Clicking on the banner will lead you to [this page](https://gearset.com/blog/salesforce-devops-approaches-maturity), where you can get access to Gearset's 2021's "The State of Salesforce DevOps" report.

#### What else changes?

That's easy: ***absolutely nothing.***

Quoting from the MSE post linked in the introduction:

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

#### When does this start? How long does it last?

The exact launch date is July 1st, 2021. The sponsorship period last for a year from the date we go live, so it'll last until June 30th, 2022.

(**Update:** This sponsorship has been extended to March 31st, 2024.)

#### I think I found a design glitch / bug.

Please report it as a separate [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Thank you!

#### I have another question or concern.

Leave an answer below (I know it might seem odd to leave a question as an answer) and we'll do our best to answer you.

Thank you again, everyone! Again, this would not have been possible without the huge amount of work you've all put into making Salesforce Stack Exchange so successful.

Comment: Just an FYI Gearset chose to extend the sponsorship to September, 30th 2023.

Comment: Hi JNat, looks like I don't see the sponsorship logo on the header anymore, only Gearset ads on the sidebar. Did something happen with the sponsorship?

Comment: @AndrewT. I see it in incognito mode - do you have an ad blocker? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJSan.png

Comment: @Catija hmm, I just checked on Chrome v109, incognito mode, no extension, Windows 10 and Android 12, on WiFi and mobile data. I checked the Developer Tools, and I saw the `<div>` for the sponsorship, but I don't know why it's not loaded :/

Comment: @AndrewT. Looks like it may have been made region-specific, so we're seeing if we can update that. Hopefully that should address the issue.

Comment: Just a heads up that Gearset opted to extend their site sponsorship to March  31st, 2024.